# Translating “Watch (blank)!”

Tags: expressions, traduction, argot

It’s pretty common in English to say something like “Watch (blank)!” when you expect something to happen that would be funny or contrary to what was being discussed.

For example:

Someone could say “I’m going to go try to fix my car... wish me luck!” and since they’re not very handy with that type of thing, someone else might say “Watch him get blown up!” to imply that he’ll mess it up so bad that the car explodes.

Or someone could say “I studied for 8 hours last night!” and someone might say to someone else “Yeah, right. Watch him fail,” because it is unexpected and funny.

Is there any way you could translate this in French? This type of humor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal translation would be simply *Regarde*, possibly with a complement (eg *regarde, il va se planter*), but it implies that the interlocutors are actually looking, not in a metaphorical way.

Some common phrases, depending on the context, may be:

> J'attends de voir (means you expect the person to fail, but still, you give him/her a slight chance to prove you wrong)
>
> On va se marrer (means it will be funny, even a bit cruel - can also be ironical)

Comment: okay je n’étais pas sûr s’il y aurait un équivalent en français donc je suis content ! alors, ce serait « j’attends de voir qu’il se plante » et « on va se marrer s’il se plante » ? quelque chose comme ça ?

Comment: Non, on dira simplement "J'attends de voir" (p.ex. "Je te promets que je rentrerai tôt de cette soirée  -Ouais... J'attends de voir !") ou "on va se marrer" (p ex. Un étudiant affirme "j'ai étudié toute la nuit pour cet examen". Un de ses amis dit à un autre "attends... on va se marrer." Cela implique "on va se marrer parce qu'il va rater"). Ces expressions sont en effet plus implicites que les "watch this/watch that".

Comment: ah je vois, merci tellement !

Comment: Un conseil: on dit "merci beaucoup" ou "encore merci" ( si on a déjà remercié une première fois) ou "Un grand merci" (plus amical), mais jamais "merci tellement" (je suppose que vous avez traduit "thank you so much") : )

Comment: ah bon? j’ai toujours dit ça et je ne l’ai jamais su ! eh bien encore merci pour ce conseil, je m’en souviendrai !

Answer (score 0):

(*Désolé pour le choix de langue dans l'explication qui suit, elle était trop avancée lorsque je me suis rendu compte qu'elle ne correspondait pas.*)

**A**

Un moyen de rendre ce qu'il y a de  percutant dans l'anglais « Watch (blank) » en respectant la syntaxe, n'existerait  que lorsque l'action **prend place immédiatement sous les yeux des interlocuteurs** et qu'elle est **brève** (assez brève pour que les personne présentes n'aient pas à attendre trop longtemps pour qu'elle se termine, même s'ils vont la regarder jusqu'à la fin), ceci pour reprendre la réponse de user **[Greg](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36431/17649)** mais en y ajoutant un détail ;  on peut utiliser pour cela le verbe « regarder ».

— Je vais faire un saut périlleux arrière.
— Regardez-le s'étaler de tout son long, ça va pas louper !

contexte : un match de football à la télévision ; cas pas utilisé, action trop longue
— Lille va gagner sans effort !
— Regarde-les perdre ce quart de finale !

contexte : un match de boxe à la télévision ; cas utilisable
— Il va se reprendre, il lui reste encore quelque chose …
— Regarde-le aller au tapis !

**B**

Il y a un moyen de communiquer de façon générale le mordant de ce type de remarque mais la syntaxe est différente ; les verbes ne sont pas liés en une seule forme verbale « verbe conjugué _ verbe à l'infinitif ».

**I** Il existe une expression, assez souvent utilisée, et elle est attestée dans le TLFi, lequel précise qu'elle n'est pas tout à fait du registre de la langue courante. Cette forme à l'impératif est bien une injonction à l'intention de la personne à qui on parle et donc reste près de l'idée de « Watch » ; cependant, ce n'est pas une demande d'attendre, il s'agit seulement d'attirer l'attention dans un but donné (voir définition ci-dessous). La remarque peut aussi être adressée à la personne-même qui en est le sujet et pas seulement à un tiers (comme en anglais).

> b) À l'impér., quelque peu fam. [Pour attirer l'attention de l'interlocuteur et pour exprimer diverses nuances de pensée qu'on souhaite que celui-ci fasse siennes, cf. supra] Attends, attendez.

Il n'existe peut être pas beaucoup d'expressions typique pour compléter ; le premier et le second cas ci-dessous seront assez courants ;

- Attendez… Vous allez voir le travail ! (*populaire*)

> (TLFi) C'est du beau travail! Le travail! (pop.) [En bonne ou en mauvaise part suivant la situation]

- Attendez, vous allez voir ce qui va arriver !
- Attends,  regarde la catastrophe arriver !
- Attendez,  si vous (n')avez encore jamais essuyé un échec ça va être une première !

contexte du match de boxe de nouveau

— Il va se reprendre, il lui reste encore quelque chose …
— Attends, tu vas le voir au tapis avant longtemps !

**II** Une alternative : « Allez ». L'impératif ne représente plus véritablement une forme verbale, il s'agit d'une exclamation : on n'intime pas la personne à qui l'on parle de faire quelque chose (comme d'aller quelque part). L'intonation dans la prononciation de « allez » est un problème : seulement certaines intonations communiquent l'idée de ce qui est dit précisément ; des intensités variées des sentiments communiqués sont possibles. (Je suis loin de percevoir ces questions en assez de détail pour en donner des idées bien précises, je souhaite seulement signaler que c'est important dans le domaine de l'expression verbale, d'où la nécessité de se familiariser avec des enregistrements de dialogues réels.)

> (TLFi)  formule [de témoignage] d'agacement

- Allez, il va faire exploser un moteur maintenant et lui avec !
- Allez, un échec assuré !
- Allez, encore une ânerie !

contexte du match de boxe de nouveau

— Il va se reprendre, il lui reste encore quelque chose …
— Allez, je te donne pas cinq minutes avant qu'il soit au tapis !